# Simplify string assignment with many if() else if ()

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a way to shorten this code using Enum(?) - based on `Inputcolor`?
For example, if my `inputcolor` is `Darkblue`, I'd like to have `Administrator` as a string. How do I do that?

I don't want all this "else if".

```
if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("darkblue") == 0) 
{ 
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "Administrator", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
else if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("green") == 0) 
{   
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "B", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
else if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("ff0000") == 0) 
{   
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "C", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
else if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("3399ff") == 0) 
{ 
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "D", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
else if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("008000") == 0) 
{ 
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "E", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
else if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("00cc00") == 0) 
{ 
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "F", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
else if (inputcolor[0].CompareTo("00CC99") == 0) 
{ 
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], "G", mu + loggedprofile1[0]); 
}
```

Comment: Start by using a dictionary... Also why aren't you using == or .Equals?

Comment: I would also refer System.Drawing.Color.Blue.Name

Comment: You can use either a dictionary (as in the answer provided already) or a `switch` statement (which some people prefer...the compiler will implement using the most efficient approach, depending on the number of possibilities...a small number winds up being comparisons, while a larger number becomes a dictionary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify the assignment, it is useful to create a mapping between the two strings. A dictionary can prove useful there:

```
var colorMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "darkblue", "Administrator"},
    { "green", "B"},
    // ...
};

var key = inputcolor[0];
string output;
if (colorMapping.TryGetValue(key, out output))
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(loggedname1[0], output, mu + loggedprofile1[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is it `C# 6.0` initialize `Dictionary` syntax?

Comment: @teo [nope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx), it's basic collection initializer syntax. :)

Comment: @teo no problem, just remember the collection initializer syntax gets compiled to `Add()` calls (it basically says `colorMapping.Add("darkblue", "Administrator")`). This way you can use it on many collection types.

Comment: `ContainsKey()` is good if _all_ you care about is the presence of the key. But if you will retrieve the associated value, you should use `TryGetValue()` instead, as it accomplishes both the check for the item and the retrieval in a single call.